# Javascript open txt from url and output as HTML

Tags: javascript

Trying to get this code to work in a chrome app but its showing no results. I just want to pipe outside HTML code into a webpage.

```
document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = readTextFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ha5x038iurobx6x/Message.txt");

function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send();
    return rawFile.responseText;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get in `console`. `Same-Origin-Policy`?

Comment: No errors in script execution or on page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) method is asynchronous. So, the `onreadystatechange` callback will be invoked only when the result is fetched.

The `return` statement from the `readTextFile` function is immediately executed (returning null, or empty), while the request is still being fetched.

I changed your code to demonstrate how it should work (suggestion):

```
function setText(allText) {
    document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = allText;
}

function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                setText(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send();
}

readTextFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ha5x038iurobx6x/Message.txt");
```

### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/q26xhqub/

Comment: the code was originally not asynchronous but then i adjusted it. Looking back it makes sense now...